# aligning controls vertically in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap and css3. I want to align my controls vertically in middle but some how not able to find elegant solution to it using bootstrap classes. Pls check sample code snippet below :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <span class="fieldtext">Field 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
      <input class="form-control input-sm"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I understand that you want to create a form with the label next to the field instead of on top of it (as is the default form behaviour of Bootstrap) you should be using the `form-inline` and `form-group` classes. This way Bootstrap will align the fields with the labels for you.

See this example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInput">Field 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I run your code snippet above and it still shows label on top of input field. What I want both label and input inline and vertically aligned.

Comment: @user2185592 The label is displayed on top of the input field because you are viewing the form in a very small viewport (as is the case with your example as well). If you click the "Full page" button to see it in a larger viewport you will see the one next to the other. Alternatively, if you need to display them next to each other for smaller viewports as well you can add the relevant rules to the `.form-control` element yourself: `display: inline-block; width: auto; vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: I didn't realize that it is a view port problem. 

Later, I searched for the bootstrap document and found this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp) which works perfect. Your answer also matches it and hence marking it as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
```

```
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">   
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">previous</span>
```

just add class right(Bootstrap-class) in your carousel-control for next button and class left(Bootstrap-class) in your carousel-control for previous button in bootstrap.